# Kendo grid column width doesn't reduce beyond a point

Tags: kendo-ui, width, kendo-grid

I'm trying to have a kendo grid column extremely thin, basically like a line. Reducing the width property below 10px or 10 doesn't seem to have any effect.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
let mainGridOptions = {
                dataSource: myData,
                columns: [{
                    field: "color",
                    title: " ",
                    width: '5px' // tried even without px, just 5
                    }]
            };
```

Anyone know what's happening?

Comment: when you set the value to int, are you leaving off the single quotes? like `width: 5` and not `width: '5'`

Comment: @JamieD77 tried that too, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce it I please try with the below code snippet or look in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jayeshgoyani/x04d6p6r/).

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: "odata",
                transport: {
                    read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
                },
                pageSize: 20
            },
            height: 550,
            groupable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true,
                buttonCount: 5
            },
            columns: [{
                field: "ContactTitle",
                title: "Contact Title"
            }, {
                field: "CompanyName",
                title: "Company Name"
            }, {
                field: "Country",
                width: '5px'
            }]
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you will set the column width to '5px' then you could not see anything into column because some default spacing(Margin/padding) applied to the columns.

Comment: the width seems to work in this example, I have no idea why it wouldn't go down below '10px' for me. Almost seems like there's a minimum limit somewhere.

Comment: It might be possible that some other CSS class applied on your grid.